Finding the extremal of a non-linear, second order functional.
The question reads as follows:
Consider the functional $$J[y] = \int \limits_{0}^{1} {(y'' ^2 - 2k y)} \text{d}x$$ where $k$ is a constant. Find the extremal of $J$ satisfying the conditions $y(0) = y'(0) = 0$ and $y(1) = y'(1) = 1$.

My work so far:
To find the extremal, we need to solve the Euler-Langrange equation
$$
\begin{array}{cc} 
F_y - \frac{d}{dx} \left[ F_{y'} \right] + \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \left[ F_{y''} \right] = 0 & \implies -2k - \frac{d}{dx} [0] + \frac{d^2}{dx^2} [2y''] = 0 \\\ 
& \implies -2k + \frac{d^2}{dx^2}[2y''] = 0 \\\ & \implies \frac{d^2}{dx^2}[y''] = k
\end{array}
$$
I'm unsure of what to do at this point. Letting $u = y''$ and treating the result as an ODE leads to the following homogeneous and particular solutions:
$$\begin{array}{cc}
u_h (x) = \alpha_1 x + \alpha_0 \newline
u_p (x) = \frac{5}{24} k x^4 + \frac{1}{6} c_1 x^3 + \frac{1}{2} c_0 x^2 \newline y''(x) = u_h (x) + u_p (x) = \alpha_1 x + \alpha_0 + \frac{5}{24} k x^4 + \frac{1}{6} c_1 x^3 + \frac{1}{2} c_0 x^2
\end{array}$$
Am I on the correct path? I don't really know whether I should proceed again to solve for $y(x)$ using variation of parameters (and solving for all the constants using the boundary conditions given) or whether I've gone wrong somewhere and seriously overcomplicated something that should be far simpler.

You are overcomplicating. The solution to $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y''=k$ is $y=\frac{kx^4}{4!}+c_3x^3+c_2x^2+c_1x+c_0.$ Now use the boundary conditions to find the values of $c_0,\ldots,c_3.$

@Gonçalo Thanks, implementing your suggestion does indeed work.
I guess I failed to realize it's equivalent to solving $\frac{d^4 y}{dx^4} = k$, since $y''(x) = \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$.

Taking @Gonçalo's suggestion into account: $y(x) = \frac{1}{4!}k x^4 + \sum \limits_{i = 0}^{3} c_i x^i$ and plugging in the boundary conditions gives $y(x) = \frac{1}{4!}k x^4 - \left(1 + \frac{1}{12} k \right)x^3 + \left(2 + \frac{1}{4!}k \right)x^2$.

Thanks. I'd gotten that, but mistakenly thought $12 = 3!$
